# Python: Escape Characters not being interpreted

Tags: python, windows, macos, escaping, character

For some reason when I write an escape character in my code, the escape character is never interpreted. Could the fact that I used to work in Windows and now changed to Mac have anything to do with it? Before when I worked in windows I've never had this problem. I've tried searching but haven't found anything on this. Thank you in advance for your help!

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
print 'Hello \nWorld'
```

From this you'd expect to get:

```
>> Hello 
>> World
```

But instead IDLE prints out exactly:

```
>> 'Hello \nWorld'
```

Answer (score 8):

You are not printing the string, you are printing the string literal; it is the strings representation:

```
>>> 'Hello\nWorld'
'Hello\nWorld'
>>> print 'Hello\nWorld'
Hello
World
>>> print repr('Hello\nWorld')
'Hello\nWorld'
```

Whenever you echo a variable in the Python interactive interpreter (or IDLE), the interpreter echoes the value back to you:

```
>>> var = 'Hello\nWorld'
>>> var
'Hello\nWorld'
```

Printing the value, however, outputs to the same location, but is a different action altogether:

```
>>> print var
Hello
World
```

If I were to call a function that printed, for example, *and* that function returned a value, you'd see both echoed to the screen:

```
>>> function foo():
...     print 'Hello\nWorld'
...     return 'Goodbye\nWorld'
...
>>> foo()
Hello
World
'Goodbye\nWorld'
```

In the above example, `Hello` and `World` were printed by the function, but `'Goodbye\nWorld'` is the return value of the function, which the interpreter helpfully echoed back to me in the form of it's representation.

Comment: *You are not printing the string, you are printing the string literal;(...)* As there's no difference between the two (what is clearly shown in your very own examples) I don't know what's the purpose of stating this. It seems you haven't noticed that the problem is that OP claims he gets `'Hello \nWorld'` as the output after evaluating `print 'Hello \nWorld'` in IDLE which is not true.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: `'Hello\nWorld'` is a string literal. The newline is escaped, it is surrounded by quotes. That is a big difference from `Hello` - newline - `World`. I did see what the OP was confused between `print expression` and just `expression`, which is why I was demonstrating the difference.